# Get the unique row number for the same flag when it changes to other flag in the next row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I am new to **`T-SQL`**.

Can anyone please help me to get this?

I have the following data:

```
Id  flg  rnum
--------------
11  n   1
11  n   2
11  y   3
11  n   4
11  n   5
11  y   6
11  n   7
```

I want to get the unique row number for the same flag when it changes to other flag in the next row.

**Desired result:**

```
Id  flg  rnum ranks
-------------------
11  n   1    1
11  n   2    1
11  y   3    2
11  n   4    3
11  n   5    3
11  y   6    4  
11  n   7    5
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`LAG() OVER ([ PARTITION BY .. ] ORDER BY...)`](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-dense_rank-function/) window analytic function together with another analytic function `SUM() OVER ([ PARTITION BY .. ] ORDER BY...)`  :

```
WITH T2 AS
(
SELECT *, LAG(flg,1) OVER ( ORDER BY rnum ) as lg
 FROM T  --> your original table  
)
SELECT id, flg, rnum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN flg=lg THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER ( ORDER BY rnum ) AS ranks 
  FROM T2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0b139d30348bc94d45266c08f92e6b32)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #temp(id int,flag char(1),rnum int)
insert into #temp values (11,'n',1),(11,'n',2)
,(11,'y',3),(11,'n',4)
,(11,'n',5),(11,'y',6)
,(11,'n',7)

;With CTE as
(
select t.* 
,isnull(tt.rnum,t.rnum)NewRnum
from #temp t
outer apply(select top 1 rnum from #temp tt 
where t.id=tt.id and t.flag=tt.flag and t.rnum=tt.rnum+1 
order by rnum)tt
)
select * 
,dense_rank()over(order by newRNum)
from CTE

drop table #temp
```